# Find files that does not contain a string

Tags: regex, linux, grep

To find all the files that contain "foo" in current folder, I use:

```
grep -r "foo" .
```

To find all the files that contain "bar" in current folder, I use:

```
grep -r "bar" .
```

But how to find all files that does not contain 'foo' and 'bar'?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To print **lines** that do not contain some string, you use the `-v` flag:

```
grep -r -v "bar" . | grep -v "foo"
```

This gives you all lines that **do not** contain `foo` or `bar`.

To print **files** that do not contain some string, you use the `-L` flag. To non-match several strings, you can use regular expressions with the `-P` flag (there are several regex flags you can use):

```
grep -r -L -P "(foo|bar)" .
```

This prints a list of files that don't contain `foo` or `bar`.

Thanks to [Anton Kovalenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1947008/anton-kovalenko) for pointing this out.

Comment: Wrong. `-v` is about non-matching lines being present, not about *matching lines being absent*.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko You're right, I removed the `-r` in the pipe. For the "non-matching lines", that's what the OP is asking for: `grep -v "foo"` goves lines that do not match `foo`.

Comment: He asks about files that *don't contain* foo and bar *at all*, not about files that *contain some non-bar lines and some non-foo lines*.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko Oh of course, I just got the subtility, I read a bit too fast.

Answer (score 7):

Recursively searches directories for all files that do no contains XYZ

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -L "XYZ"
```

Comment: I tried your solution and the result is the opposite. I got all files that contained XYZ.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
  grep  -L -e  "foo\|bar" *
```

Answer (score 2):

With awk, something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {f=ARGV[1] ; ff=0} f != FILENAME { if ( ff>0 ) { print f } ; ff=0 ; f=FILENAME } /SEARCHSTRING/ {ff=1} END {if ( ff>0 ) { print f } }' INPUT_FILE_LIST(PATTERN)
```

Basically it reads every input file and if sees your `SEARCHSTRING` (which can be a regex), it saves that info. After finishing the current file (or after the last file), check if it found something, and if so, print the previous filename.

Comment: I love this over the grep-answers because I can easily specify in which files to search. Looking for _all_ files that do not import xy is much more noisy than looking for all `*.py **/*.py` files not containing an import.

Comment: I do not understand how 'print the previous filename if match is found in the current file' solves the question at all.

I have confirmed on my files that the results of this are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below. this should work

> grep -rL -P "(foo|bar)" .