# SublimeText3 - Find all files without a string?

Tags: sublimetext3

I've looked around quite a bit for an answer to this, but I cannot seem to find what I need. Is it possible with SublimeText3 > Find in Files to do a search for all files that DO NOT include a string?

I've tried toggling the Regular Expressions button beside "Find:" and entering a value, but I'm not a regex pro, so I may be doing it wrong?

For example, I want to find all files in a designated folder that DO NOT have the following string:

social-links

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for *all* files in your directory in question (for anything, like a space or the letter e...assuming every file has a space or letter e!), and copy all those file-paths to a new file.

Search for all files *with the word*, and paste that path-list into a second file.

Sort both files, then compare them to see which lines--which paths--are missing from the has-the-word file. Those are the ones you want.

---

As far as a single find-in-files search, I don't see how you would do that in Sublime or any other basic text editor. Here is some more information:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26836/how-can-i-find-all-files-that-do-not-contain-a-text-string
- *[Find files that does not contain a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809800/find-files-that-does-not-contain-a-string)*
- *[How to find all files that do NOT contain specific string in windows environment Visual Studio or any other IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223753/how-to-find-all-files-that-do-not-contain-specific-string-in-windows-environment)*

---

Good luck!

Comment: This could work, however, is there an easy way to get just the path list from a Find Results?