# How to find files excluding text

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, grep, find

I was using this command `find . -type f -exec grep -Hn 'TEXT' {} \;` in terminal to find all files where `TEXT` is in file, but right now I want to find all the files in current directory where `TEXT` isn't in the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using grep to find files that don't contain a given string pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748129/using-grep-to-find-files-that-dont-contain-a-given-string-pattern) and [Find files that does not contain a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809800/find-files-that-does-not-contain-a-string)

Comment: Yes, it's a dublicate. Couldn't find this link before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html)-compliant `grep` implementations should have `-v` option:

```
-v
Select lines not matching any of the specified patterns. If the -v
option is not specified, selected lines shall be those that match any
of the specified patterns.
```

So command to list files that do not contain `TEXT` should be:

```
$ find . -type f -exec grep -lv 'TEXT' {} \;
```

Comment: OP asks for "where TEXT isn't in the file", not for lines in the file, not holding the string...

Comment: You're probably right. I just copied a command OP has given and added `-v` but `-lv` would be better here. I will fix my answer.

Comment: @Abecee: BTW, my first downvote, thank you ;) !

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Sorry, I needed to search better :)